# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for length in 73

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

I am trying to build a simple app as part of my assignment, but I was asked to use jQuery and PHP, which to be honest, I only know at a superficial level.

My goal is to build a table where I have the api name, a small summary of what it does, and a button where the event will start when clicked.

The objective is to have the return of the api call show in the table at the bottom, (it does not need to look good, only needs to be functional)

However, after converting json to an object, I cannot access what I need.

I am able to console.log the result:

```
{"elevation":73,"lng":-8.666666666666666,"observation":"LPPR 140900Z 13011KT CAVOK 13/03 Q1025","ICAO":"LPPR","clouds":"clouds and visibility OK","dewPoint":"3","cloudsCode":"CAVOK","datetime":"2023-02-14 09:00:00","countryCode":"PT","temperature":"13","humidity":50,"stationName":"Porto / Pedras Rubras","weatherCondition":"n/a","windDirection":130,"hectoPascAltimeter":1025,"windSpeed":"11","lat":41.21666666666667}
```

but when I try to access the keys, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search

This is my markup and code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table-container">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Api Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Checks</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="apiName">Wikipedia</td>
            <td class="apiDescription">Wikipedia summary of searched topic</td>
            <td>
              <button id="wikiBtn">Check</button>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="apiName">Airport Weather</td>
            <td class="apiDescription">
              Checks in realtime weather conditions
            </td>
            <td>
              <button id="wthBtn">Check</button>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="apiName">City Status</td>
            <td class="apiDescription">Checks the status of a city</td>
            <td>
              <button class="cityBtn">Check</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="results"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  outline: 3px solid #eee;
}

.table-container {
  margin: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-container thead tr {
  background-color: #009879;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-container th,
.table-container td {
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

.table-container tbody td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

jQuery:

```
// Weather Script:
$('#wthBtn').click(function () {
  // alert("test");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'libs/php/wthApi.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
      $('#results').html('');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      $.each(result, function (i, item) {
        console.log(item);
        $.each(item, function (index, val) {
          $('#results').append('Date: ' + val.datetime + '<br/>');
          $('#results').append('Clouds: ' + val.clouds + '<br/>');
          $('#results').append(
            'Wind Direction: ' + val.windDirection + '<br/>'
          );
          $('#results').append('Wind Speed: ' + val.windSpeed + '<br/>');
          $('#results').append('Temperature: ' + val.temperature + '<br/>');
          $('#results').append('Humidity: ' + val.humidity + '<br/>');
        });
      });
    },
  });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// API source url with predefined parameters 
$url = 'http://api.geonames.org/weatherIcaoJSON?ICAO=LPPR&username=joselages';

// Initialize Curl 
$ch = curl_init();

// FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec//() instead of outputting it directly.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//Execute the cURL object and stores the result to $result.
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//print_r($result);

// Finish the session.
curl_close($ch);

// Convert JSON string into an object. 
$decode = json_decode($result, true);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($decode);
```

I have tried a few things, however it does not work, I have tried to follow this guide: [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php)

But not even that is helping me.
Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong and what am I missing?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please clarify what part of the code the error is referring to.

Comment: And please reduce this to the information that is _necessary_ to understand or reproduce the problem. That for example the CSS you have shown, has _anything_ to do with this, seems highly unlikely. So in that case, it would be just _noise_ that makes your question longer than necessary, and is basically just a distraction.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dataType: 'json',` then jQuery will automatically convert the incoming JSON String into a javascript object.

Remove the `,true` from this line

```
$decode = json_decode($result, true);
```

to

```
$decode = json_decode($result);
```

and an Object instead of an array will be returned from the PHP to the javascript

If you look at the object returned from the API you will see its content

```
stdClass Object
(
    [weatherObservation] => stdClass Object
        (
            [elevation] => 73
            [lng] => -8.6666666666667
            [observation] => LPPR 141230Z 11010KT CAVOK 17/05 Q1023
            [ICAO] => LPPR
            [clouds] => clouds and visibility OK
            [dewPoint] => 5
            [cloudsCode] => CAVOK
            [datetime] => 2023-02-14 12:30:00
            [countryCode] => PT
            [temperature] => 17
            [humidity] => 45
            [stationName] => Porto / Pedras Rubras
            [weatherCondition] => n/a
            [windDirection] => 110
            [hectoPascAltimeter] => 1023
            [windSpeed] => 10
            [lat] => 41.216666666667
        )

)
```

So when this gets sent to the javascript and converted to a javascript object you can address it as `result.weatherObservation.something`

```
// Weather Script:
$('#wthBtn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'libs/php/wthApi.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#results').html('');
            
            $('#results').append('Date: ' + 
                            result.weatherObservation.datetime + '<br/>');
            $('#results').append('Clouds: ' + 
                            result.weatherObservation.clouds + '<br/>');
            $('#results').append( 'Wind Direction: ' + 
                            result.weatherObservation.windDirection + '<br/>');
            $('#results').append('Wind Speed: ' + 
                            result.weatherObservation.windSpeed + '<br/>');
            $('#results').append('Temperature: ' + 
                            result.weatherObservation.temperature + '<br/>');
            $('#results').append('Humidity: ' + 
                            result.weatherObservation.humidity + '<br/>');
        }
    }); 
});
```

> You may want to add an error method on this for completeness